# Find a first-order differential equation satisfied by all circles through the points $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I can write out the characteristic equation for such circles, then I can find a desired first-order differential equation. The problem is how to write the characteristic equation?

Comment: Center of your circle is equidistant of both $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0).$ Therefore its center should be on the $y$ axis.

Comment: @Nilan: Thanks. I guess I see the way: $x^{2} + (y-c)^{2} = 1+c^{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circle center has to be some $C=(0,c)$ and your circle's equation would be $|X - C|^2 = x^2 + (y-c)^2 = 1 + c^2$.

Comment: Thanks for concern :) Just arrived at the same result

Comment: For your efforts, yes no problem.

Comment: Consider upvoting my question too, would you please.

Comment: Mostly for not leaving it in the unanswered stats and to be a good SE citizen but I guess the effort is worth it too :)